# SQL Server. Elevate signed procedure permissions to read client IP from server state

Tags: sql-server, permissions, procedure, signed

Yet another request to capture client's IP from trigger... e.g. when client updates table. In our case the database is not subject to TRUTHWORTHY option. Client soft is old and huge and ugly and there is no way to send IP from all its db calls. I've tryed with no success some compilation of copy-pastes... as follows:

```
-- Create a test login and test database
CREATE LOGIN testuser WITH PASSWORD = 'CeRT=0=TeST'
CREATE DATABASE certtest
go
-- Move to the test database.
USE certtest
go
-- Create the test user.
CREATE USER testuser
go
CREATE PROCEDURE example_sp AS
   SELECT  client_net_address as client_ip  FROM  sys.dm_exec_connections   WHERE   session_id = @@SPID
go
GRANT EXECUTE ON example_sp TO public
go
-- Create the certificate.
CREATE CERTIFICATE examplecert
   ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'All you need is love'
   WITH SUBJECT = 'Certificate for example_sp',
   START_DATE = '20020101', EXPIRY_DATE = '20200101'
go

-- transfer certificate to master
BACKUP CERTIFICATE [examplecert] TO FILE = 'C:\TEMP\examplecert.CER';
GO
USE [master]
GO
CREATE CERTIFICATE [examplecert2] FROM FILE = 'C:\TEMP\examplecert.CER';
--EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_delete_file  'del C:\TEMP\examplecert.CER';

-- create user able to read sys.dm_exec_connections
CREATE USER examplecertuser FROM CERTIFICATE [examplecert2]

GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO examplecertuser
GRANT AUTHENTICATE TO examplecertuser --?
go

USE certtest
--GRANT SELECT ON testtbl TO examplecertuser
--go
-- Sign the procedure.
ADD SIGNATURE TO example_sp BY CERTIFICATE examplecert
    WITH PASSWORD = 'All you need is love'
go
-- Run as the test user, to actually see that this works.
EXECUTE AS USER = 'testuser'
go
-- run the signed procedure. 
EXEC example_sp
go
-- Become ourselves again.
REVERT
go
-- Clean up
USE master
DROP DATABASE certtest
DROP LOGIN testuser
DROP USER examplecertuser
DROP CERTIFICATE examplecert2
```

Still no rights for testuser error. 
Fix suggestions or working sample (if possible) would be appreciated )). 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This seems working ...

```
-- Create a test login and test database
CREATE DATABASE certtest
go
-- Move to the test database.
use certtest
go
CREATE LOGIN testuser WITH PASSWORD = 'CeRT=0=TeST'
CREATE USER testuser FROM LOGIN testuser  -- Create the test user.

go
CREATE PROCEDURE example_sp 
    @ip VARCHAR(48) OUTPUT
    AS
BEGIN   
   SELECT  @ip = client_net_address FROM  sys.dm_exec_connections   WHERE   session_id = @@SPID   
END
go
GRANT EXECUTE ON example_sp TO public
go
-- Create the certificate.

go
CREATE CERTIFICATE examplecert
   ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'All you need is love'
   WITH SUBJECT = 'Certificate for example_sp',
   START_DATE = '20020101', EXPIRY_DATE = '20200101'
go

-- transfer certificate to master
BACKUP CERTIFICATE [examplecert] TO FILE = 'C:\TEMP\exampleCert.CER';
GO
USE [master]
GO

CREATE CERTIFICATE [examplecert] FROM FILE = 'C:\TEMP\examplecert.CER'

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'examplecertuserz')
BEGIN
DROP USER [examplecertuserz] 
DROP LOGIN [examplecertuserz] 
END
go

CREATE LOGIN [examplecertuserz]
    FROM CERTIFICATE examplecert
GO
CREATE USER [examplecertuserz]
REVOKE CONNECT SQL FROM [examplecertuserz]
GO 
GRANT AUTHENTICATE SERVER TO [examplecertuserz]
GO
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO [examplecertuserz]
go

USE certtest

go
ADD SIGNATURE TO example_sp BY CERTIFICATE examplecert  WITH PASSWORD =  'All you need is love'

go
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'testuser'

go
-- Then run the signed procedure. 
declare @ip as varchar(48)

exec example_sp @ip OUTPUT
select @ip
go

-- Become ourselves again.
REVERT
go
-- Clean up
USE master
DROP DATABASE certtest
DROP LOGIN testuser
DROP LOGIN examplecertuserz
DROP USER examplecertuserz

DROP CERTIFICATE examplecert
```